# Path to conda environment as a variable in script

Tags: python, path, virtualenv, conda, spyder

I am using Spyder and I am working with a virtual environment created with conda create, which is located in C:/Users/username/.conda/envs/...

To deal with GDAL proj.db error (proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db) I need to set:
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = "C:/Users/username/.conda/envs/test/Library/share/proj"

Because I am not writing the script only for me, I would like to write a line to **find a path to the current conda environment** and save it as 'conda_env_path' variable (in my case C:/Users/username/.conda/envs/test).

All the answers I found say about finding path to environment in anaconda prompt, not as a line of a script.
  Thank you.

Comment: You can use shell commands in Python to get the path to your env and store the result in a variable like this : `conda_env_path = os.popen('conda info --base').read().split('\n')[0]`. And replace `base` with your virtual environment name.

Comment: Can you use `CONDA_PREFIX`? That'll be the directory of the currently active environment. Also, please link the answers you have tried, but didn't work out.

Comment: @MKDYasserH
Thank you for the 'shell commands' idea, that is what I was looking for :) 
Unfortunately, I get an error:  usage: conda-script.py [-h] [-V] command ...
conda-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --test. And it also doesn't work in Anaconda prompt. Lastly, it would be perfect to be able to access the path to the current env, without specifying its name.

Comment: @merv To be able to use CONDA_PREFIX i would need to create env with 'conda create --prefix ./envs', right?

Comment: No. If the script is running in a Conda environment, then `os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX']` will be defined.

Comment: @merv Somehow it didn't work, but on Monday I will go back to this script and will try to check it again.